# PHP interface for JMeter

Tags: php, reporting, lamp, jmeter

We are looking into using JMeter for benchmarking and load testing on our servers but would like to have the data from the reports automatically dumped into our database to be used with JCharts or perhaps even importing it into munin for graphing and analysis. Does anyone know of an interface that could help us achieve our goal? We would rather not spend the time writing one ourselves if there already is a way to do this. Through reading I've seen that the data from JMeter can be outputted in XML format and we could just parse that but were looking for a better option. Any suggestions or feedback is welcome. Thanks in advance!

If anyone has a suggestion for another way to go about this please let me know!

Comment: I'm working on such service, haven't released it yet... Still a lot of work to do with it.

Comment: Well if you can get it done soon you may have a customer!

Comment: God, let it be 48 hours in a day!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe CSV is the better option for you. It's one of two formats and then it should be trivial to import into a database. Do you need pointers? If so, let me know which database etc..

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Till you can save results as an XML file for processing by your php program.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try such service now: [Loadosophia.org](http://loadosophia.org)

Answer (score 0):

CSV is the best option. You can convert the report.csv to HTML or you can dump into your database(your requirement).